# Accessing the system PATH in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, path

I've been trying to use matplotlib in pgf mode on OS X 10.9, however I ran into an issue where xelatex was not found when called by the library (I have a full texlive install in the PATH).

I did some digging:

```
from subprocess import call
call("source .bash_profile", shell=True) #I tried this as a python console startup script to see if I could get it to update the PATH.
print("Current bin path:")
call("echo $PATH", shell=True)
```

yields

```
Current bin path:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

whereas 'echo $PATH' in a terminal gives

```
 /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

How can I get python to see xelatex as it should. Matplotlib says that xelatex needs to be available on the PATH - according to 'which xelatex' it is.

As a temporary solution i have

```
ln -s /usr/texbin/xelatex /usr/bin/xelatex
```

and this gives a temporary solution, but is far from solid long term if I need other binaries get called.

Many thanks for any ideas.

EDIT: Jan's comment made me remember the difference between the systemwide PATH and the PATH set by the profile. I edited /etc/paths to include /usr/texbin and that didn't help either.

If it was my program I would call xelatex by its absolute location, but I'd rather not mess around with marplotlib's src unless I have to. For now I will continue to use symbolic links, but if anyone has a more elegant solution please post here.

Answer (score 0):

## Find `xelatex` abs path and call that

Instead of manipulating `PATH` (and you probably have it changed only untill the `.bash_profile` script terminates, but this I am not sure about), I would recommend to call `xelatex` explicitly by full abs path.